# Button without using form/submit buttons and updating info

Tags: javascript

new here. Currently lost at my programming. I can't seem to make use of buttons in my page. I want to update my contents once I pressed any of the two button. Here's where I'm stuck at:

```js
var value = 1; //set default to 1
var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");

button1.onClick = function()
{
 value = 1;
}

button2.onClick = function()
{
 value = 2;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" value="1" id="button1">Store 1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md" value="2" id="button2">Store 2</button>

<!-- the following lines are under td of a table -->
<tr>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    if (value == 1)
    {
      coolerName = "Corsair H100i v2";
      coolerPrice = 5440;
    }
    if (value == 2)
    {
      coolerName = "Corsair H100i v2";
      coolerPrice = 5450;
    }
    document.write("<td>" + coolerName + "</td>");
    document.write('<td id="alignRight">');
    if (coolerPrice > 0)
    {
      document.write(coolerPrice.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,'));
    }
    else
    {
      document.write(coolerPrice.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,'));
    }
    document.write('</td>');
  </script>
</tr>
```

Do I need to do AJAX here, or JScript is good?

Comment: you'd need ajax if you wanted to get some additional data from the server. Do you need to do that? If not then script is sufficient. But simply writing `value = 1;` on its own in your onclick function doesn't change anything except the value of that variable. If you want to update something on-screen within the HTML as a result of that click, you need some more code within the click method (or call a function from the click function) which will actually change your HTML. The code you've got at the moment breaks immediately in the snippet because `value` doesn't exist until you click a button

Comment: that code runs immediately when you initialise the page, it doesnt wait for the button click, which it needs to. Wrap it in a function which accepts `value` as a parameter, and call that function from each of your click functions, passing your new `value` into it. And there are better ways to write to the DOM than `document.write` - setting the innerHTML of an existing element is cleaner and safer.

Comment: do i need to go put the ajax auto-refresh command inside the onclick function or outside?

Comment: sorry I'm confused? What ajax command? There's no ajax in your code currently. And what do you mean by an "auto-refresh" command, exactly? Your question seems unrelated to any of the comments above. Did you understand what I wrote?

Comment: yea, haven't implemented any ajax yet. yea i got it, all happens since value was set at 1 and everything with condition of (value == 1) is printed to the screen.

Comment: ok well if you want something to happen via ajax after you click the button, then yes, you need the code which makes the ajax call start to be put within the "click" function(s). The actual ajax could could be in a separate function, which is just called from the "click" function(s) with any necessary parameters. Then it can be re-usable across both buttons if that's what you need. The basic principle is that anything you want to happen as a result of the click must be triggered from within the "click" function.